# Did Android ever have an option to disable apps?

Tags: vanilla-android

The way [the Google support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2521768?hl=en) ("Android 8.1 and up") is written suggests that this option may have been only available in third-party ROMs:

> **Disable apps that came with your phone**
>
> You can’t delete some system apps that came pre-installed on your
> Android phone. But on some phones, you can turn them off so that they
> won't show on the list of apps on your phone. To learn how to disable
> apps, contact your device manufacturer.

I don't personally have an issue with bloatware as I run LineageOS, but temporarily turning off apps would have often been beneficial for various reasons (some, while useful, are rarely used and may run at boot; issues with the latest update and no roll-back option).

Comment: With root privileges you can disable any app.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: Natively in Android?

Comment: What does that mean? Aren't we talking about Android?

Comment: AFAIK, based on my personal experience, even without root, system apps can only be disabled (and uninstall updates, but not uninstall the app) on vanilla Android 2.x (or in fact, probably older than that). And I've also disabled some LineageOS' built-in apps since I don't intend to use it. Open the app's info and you can either disable (for system apps) or uninstall (for user apps).

Comment: @AndrewT. apps signed with system certificate cannot be disabled from app's info: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/Utils.java#275

Comment: @IrfanLatif hmm, I probably need a distinction between "apps signed with system certificate" and "apps that reside on the system partition"... also, is this limitation added since Android 10 (or even Android 8.1)? I also have to clarify that most of my experience is still limited up to Android 7.x...

Comment: @AndrewT. I think it's so since early days of Android.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: Yes, I meant if apps can or could be disabled in the Android user interface (without running ADB or some third-party root apps for instance).

Comment: @AndrewT.: LineageOS does indeed have a disable option for some of its system apps (such as "email" and "browser").

Comment: @user598527 you need to execute `pm disable <pkg_name>`. Do it the way you like; through ADB shell, some terminal emulator app, a shell script, or simply from within some file explorer app (if it supports executing commands).